# What does the __completion_signature concept in stdexec (senders/ receivers) do?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++26

I'm looking at the [reference implementation](https://github.com/NVIDIA/stdexec) of [P2300](https://wg21.link/p2300r7) (the senders and receivers proposal).

I'm having trouble understanding [some of the code](https://github.com/NVIDIA/stdexec/blob/5d3cc97a328e79c897fad4824ceb5c73cff5d0a3/include/stdexec/execution.hpp#L606):

```cpp
namespace __compl_sigs {
    template <same_as<set_value_t> _Tag, class _Ty = __q<__types>, class... _Args>
    __types<__minvoke<_Ty, _Args...>> __test(_Tag (*)(_Args...));

    template <same_as<set_error_t> _Tag, class _Ty = __q<__types>, class _Error>
    __types<__minvoke<_Ty, _Error>> __test(_Tag (*)(_Error));

    template <same_as<set_stopped_t> _Tag, class _Ty = __q<__types>>
    __types<__minvoke<_Ty>> __test(_Tag (*)());

    template <class, class = void>
    __types<> __test(...);

    template <class _Tag, class _Ty = void, class... _Args>
    void __test(_Tag (*)(_Args...) noexcept) = delete;

    template <class _Sig>
    concept __completion_signature = __typename<decltype(__compl_sigs::__test((_Sig*) nullptr))>;
} // namespace __compl_sigs

using __compl_sigs::__completion_signature;

// [...]

template <__compl_sigs::__completion_signature... _Sigs>
struct completion_signatures {
    // Uncomment this to see where completion_signatures is
    // erroneously getting instantiated:
    //static_assert(sizeof...(_Sigs) == -1u);
};
```

Fundamentally, can someone give me an example for a sender and what `__types<__minvoke<_Ty, _Args...>>`, `__types<__minvoke<_Ty, _Error>>` and `__types<__minvoke<_Ty>>` actually mean? I understand that they relate to `set_value`, `set_error` and `set_stopped`.

Finally, what is the use for `completion_signatures`?

Comment: https://wg21.link/p2300r7#spec-execution.snd_rec_utils.completion_sigs and https://wg21.link/p2300r7#completion-signature might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`completion_signatures<Ts...>` shall be a type list where each `Ts` is either

- `set_value_t(Args...)`
- `set_error_t(E)`
- `set_stopped_t()`

What you see in the implementation is, that a concept `__completion_signature` is defined such that each `Ts` of matches one of those forms. Otherwise, you cannot instantiate this template class. Note, that you are missing the definition of the `__typename` concept in your snippet, which is

```cpp
  template <class... _Ts>
  concept __typename = requires { typename __types<_Ts...>; };
```

Each sender defines at least two methods

`execution::connect(sender, receiver) -> operation`
`execution::get_completion_signatures(sender, env) -> completion_signatures<...>`

This constrained type list describes the possible completions of the async operation that results from the connect method.

Whenever you define a custom sender in P2300, you not only code the async code via the CPOs `execution::connect` (and `execution::start` for the operation) but you also have to manually code the type transformations on the completion signatures via the `execution::get_completion_signatures` CPO.

Unfortunately, it is not possible, or feasible, to compute the completion signatures automatically. Knowing the set of possible completions is necessary to store the results in intermediate containers within algorithms, such as `execution::let_value` or `execution::when_all`.